# Hamcrest isEqualIgnoringWhitespace does not Ignore whitespace

Tags: java, unit-testing, whitespace, matcher, hamcrest

So as we need to parse some HTML to XML and validate that everything from the HTML is in the XML file we use Hamcrest in Unittests for validation. As we can not have more or less information in the XML files it is important that we have a matcher that does not use a `contains` but an `equalTo`. The problem is that we parse but have to extract certain elements as they are not allowed in the externally managed datamodel. We found out that doing so migth add extra whitespaces in some cases (has something to do with Jsoup).

So as the spaces are not relevant in the actual content we decided to ignore those for now (as this is purely PoC), but we do want validation of our concept. To do this I came up with a solution that strips every whitespace (`String.replaceAll("\\s","")`) which also strips newlines and tabs. All the text is then concatenated into one String object which makes for terrible reading and also not a very good practice when debugging at all. So instead I opted to use Hamcrests [IsEqualIgnoringWhitespace](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/text/IsEqualIgnoringWhiteSpace.html). When testing I found out that it does not do anything like the name suggests at all. In the code there is no deletion of spaces, tabs or newlines but instead it checks if the current character is a whitespace and if so if the character before that also contained a whitespace. If that is the case it will remove one whitespace. So bassically it only normalises the whitespaces to contain only one of them in between two words.

Here is the code of the used `stripSpace` method in the class:

```
public String stripSpace(String toBeStripped) {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean lastWasSpace = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < toBeStripped.length(); i++) {
        char c = toBeStripped.charAt(i);
        if (isWhitespace(c)) {
            if (!lastWasSpace) {
                result.append(' ');
            }
            lastWasSpace = true;
        } else {
            result.append(c);
            lastWasSpace = false;
        }
    }
    return result.toString().trim();
}
```

So in essence it does not ignore whitespaces at all. Why is it named like this then?

to give some examples of inputs we want to match with one another here is some of the text that has whitespaces but shouldn't (text is in dutch but this doesn't matter):

`m2` vs. `m 2` (HTML original: `m<sup>2</sup>`)

`Tabel 3.1` vs. `Tabel 3 .1` (HTML original: `Tabel <a href="link to table">3</a>.1`)

So as these texts will never be matched by a normal `equalTo` matcher, the `equalToIgnoringWhitespaces` should actually match this based on the name but it doesn't.

Does anyone of you know if there actually is a matcher that actually ignores whitespaces?

Comment: Hamcrest since deprecated this & renamed it to: `Matchers.equalToCompressingWhiteSpace`  Maybe someone out there heard you. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Javadocs `IsEqualIgnoringWhitespace`:

> Creates a matcher of String that matches when the examined string is equal to the specified expectedString, when whitespace differences are (mostly) ignored.

This is explained in more detail in the `Matchers` Javadocs:

> Creates a matcher of String that matches when the examined string is equal to the specified expectedString, when whitespace differences are (mostly) ignored. To be exact, the following whitespace rules are applied:
>
> - all leading and trailing whitespace of both the expectedString and the examined string are ignored
> - any remaining whitespace, appearing within either string, is collapsed to a **single** space before comparison

The following test verifies this behaviour:

```
@Test
public void testIsEqualIgnoringWhitespace() {
    // leading and trailing spaces are ignored
    assertThat("m 2", equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace(" m 2 "));

    // all other spaces are collapsed to a single space
    assertThat("m 2", equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace("m     2"));

    // does not match because the single space in the expected string is not collapsed any further
    assertThat("m2", not(equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace("m 2")));
}
```

So, that explains why you are seeing the behaviour your described in your question.

Re this:

> Does anyone of you know if there actually is a matcher that actually ignores whitespaces?

You could write your own matcher. Here's an example:

```
public class IgnoresAllWhitespacesMatcher extends BaseMatcher<String> {
    public String expected;

    public static IgnoresAllWhitespacesMatcher ignoresAllWhitespaces(String expected) {
        return new IgnoresAllWhitespacesMatcher(expected);
    }

    private IgnoresAllWhitespacesMatcher(String expected) {
        this.expected = expected.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object actual) {
        return expected.equals(actual);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(String.format("the given String should match '%s' without whitespaces", expected));
    }
}
```

Using this matcher the following test passes:

```
@Test
public void testUsingCustomIgnoringAllWhitespaceMatcher() {
    // leading and trailing spaces are ignored
    assertThat("m2", ignoresAllWhitespaces(" m 2 "));

    // intermediate spaces are ignored
    assertThat("m2", ignoresAllWhitespaces("m     2"));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we strip white-spaces in actual string as well? So "  m   2" would match "m      
  2    "